# How to set NTP synchronized to yes in Linux without NTP sync?

Tags: systemd, ntp, clock

How to set NTPSynchronized to yes in Linux without actual NTP synchronization?

I just want to cheat some program.

```
]$ timedatectl show -p NTPSynchronized
NTPSynchronized=yes
```

Comment: please explain what you mean by *set NTPSynchronized to yes*

Comment: You _might_ be able to synchronise NTP to the local clock. I've done that before with `ntpd` when the local clock was guaranteed to be synchronised by some other service. I've also used this approach as a backup plan to keep all servers in an enterprise synchronised to each other even if the upstream time source is lost. Just remember to set the stratum to 10 or so in these situations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the D-Bus property of `org.freedesktop.timedate1`, [the relevant D-Bus documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.timedate1.html) says:

> `NTPSynchronized` shows whether the kernel reports the time as synchronized (c.f. `adjtimex(3)`). `TimeUSec` and `RTCTimeUSec` show the current time on the system and in the RTC. The purpose of those three properties is to allow remote clients to access this information over D-Bus. Local clients can access the information directly.

It is a *read-only* property, so you cannot directly set it. However, it might be possible to modify your kernel's synchronization state using the `-S`/`--status` option of the `adjtimex` command (which usually needs to be installed as a separate package), and the D-Bus property should follow the kernel's state.

After a bit of testing, I found out that when setting the clock to a "fake synchronized" state, you'll also need to set the `maxerror` and `esterror` to some plausible values: if those are at their default "unsynchronized" values (16000000 for both), the kernel will immediately revert the status back to "unsynchronized". So, for example:

```
adjtimex --status 0 --maxerror 50632 --esterror 438
```

will make the clock appear to be synchronized (and `timedatectl` confirms it), and

```
adjtimex --status 64 --maxerror 16000000 --esterror 16000000
```

will revert back to unsynchronized state.

It actually seems like the D-Bus `NTPSynchronized` value depens more on whether the error variables are at their maximum values or not, than on the actual status value.

(I used the `maxerror` and `esterror` values I had when I had `chronyd` running, and disabled `chronyd` and rebooted for testing. Any reasonable `maxerror` and `esterror` values would probably work for faking the synchronized state.)